# How to Check join value for null and lookup in the other tables

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

If the join values of `accomm_bk` and `type_bk` is Null then how to lookup values in tables say `lookup_accomm_bk`, `lookup_type_bk`.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
select accomm_bk,type_bk
from 
staging.contract a 
left join dim.accomm_dim b on (a.accomm_id)= b.accomm_hash
left join dim.type_dim c on (a.accomm_id)= c.type_hash
```

IF Result is NULL, then how to lookup `staging.contract a`  with tables `lookup_accomm_bk` for column `accomm_bk` and  `lookup_type_bk` for column `type_bk` and get values.

Example

```
accomm_bk | type_bk
--------------------
NULL      | NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If Result is NULL, then how to lookup staging.contract a with tables lookup_accomm_bk for column accomm_bk and lookup_type_bk for column type_bk and get values.

You would need to add two more `LEFT JOIN`s to your query to link the `contract` table to tables `lookup_accomm_bk` and `lookup_type_bk`.

Then use the `COALESCE` function to display the looked up values if they can't be found in `accomm_dim` and `type_dim`.

Here is a skeleton for the query (you need to define the proper `ON` clauses for the additional `LEFT JOIN`s) :

```
select 
    COALESCE(b.accomm_bk, lb.accomm_bk),
    COALESCE(c.type_bk, lc.type_bk)
from 
    staging.contract a 
    left join dim.accomm_dim b on (a.accomm_id)= b.accomm_hash
    left join dim.type_dim c on (a.accomm_id)= c.type_hash
    left join dim.lookup_accomm_bk lb on ...
    left join dim.lookup_type_bk lc on ...
```